# Firebase onChildChanged Listener is getting fired twice

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am facing very weird issue with `firebase`, I have data in attached format in `firebase` and I am trying to fetch the data recreate whole `recyclerview` adapter list if any of child node for that conversation changed.

If I run it using debugger , it fired `onChildChanged()` only once but otherwise fire twice, Please help.

```
private void getConversations(){

    final DatabaseReference conversationRef = databaseReference.child("conversation").child(currentUser);

    // Get event fired when new child added
    conversationRef.orderByChild("time").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
            String ref= dataSnapshot.getKey();
            int position = userListRef.size();
            userListRef.add(position,ref);
            getDetailedConversations(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
                userListRef.clear();
                conversationListRef.clear();
                conversationAdapter.clear();
                //conversationAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Log.d(TAG, "new position: data changed+++++++++++++++++++++");
                conversationRef.removeEventListener(this);
                getConversations();

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {}

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {}

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}


    });
}

private void getDetailedConversations(final int position){

    DatabaseReference databaseReferenceAdapter = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    final DatabaseReference conversationRef  = databaseReferenceAdapter.child("conversation").child(currentUser).child(userListRef.get(position));

    conversationRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Single value event");
            final Conversation conversation = dataSnapshot.getValue(Conversation.class);
            conversation.setFirebaseToken(dataSnapshot.getKey());
            conversationListRef.add(conversation);
            conversationAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

LogCat :

```
11-07 22:56:01.127 15524-15577/io.ace.aceme E/Surface:
getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x9b9e2860
11-07 22:56:02.618 15524-15573/io.ace.aceme V/FA: Inactivity, 
disconnecting from AppMeasurementService
11-07 22:56:05.566 15524-15524/io.ace.aceme D/MessagesActivity: new 
position: data changed+++++++++++++++++++++
11-07 22:56:05.570 15524-15524/io.ace.aceme D/MessagesActivity: 
Single value event
11-07 22:56:05.785 15524-15524/io.ace.aceme D/MessagesActivity: new 
position: data changed+++++++++++++++++++++
11-07 22:56:05.785 15524-15524/io.ace.aceme D/MessagesActivity: 
Single value event
11-07 22:56:05.786 15524-15524/io.ace.aceme D/MessagesActivity: 
Single value event
11-07 22:56:06.134 15524-15524/io.ace.aceme D/MessagesActivity: 
Single value event
11-07 22:56:06.134 15524-15524/io.ace.aceme D/MessagesActivity: 
Single value event
11-07 22:56:06.137 15524-15524/io.ace.aceme D/MessagesActivity: 
Single value event
11-07 22:56:07.393 15524-15573/io.ace.aceme V/FA: Activity paused, 
time: 16426758
11-07 22:56:07.398 15524-15573/io.ace.aceme V/FA: Activity resumed, 
time: 16426764
```

`Firebase` Database:

Database pic

[image: image1]

Comment: onDataChange you are removing and adding listener again, it is not required.And also you are trying to combine order-by and child event listener, that is not advised use value event listner

Comment: @Shanmugam listener has to be removed otherwise it would attach more listensers on top of it, I have tried it earlier. it does not help.

Comment: Even more shocking is , when I am running it using debug mode , it called on once but I normal run it called 2 times on any child change.

Comment: what is your requirement?your Implementation is wrong...

Comment: my requirment is fetch all conversation of one user, In my code I am fetching the reference path first and then do SingleValue listener to get Conversation object. if you look at snapshot you can understand quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the updated query , no need to use orderBy

```
private void getConversations(){

final DatabaseReference conversationRef = databaseReference.child("conversation").child(currentUser);

// Get event fired when new child added
conversationRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
        String ref= dataSnapshot.getKey();
        int position = userListRef.size();
        userListRef.add(position,ref);
        getDetailedConversations(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
            //Here no need to clear and reload
            //just find the user in list and update the corresponding object and call notifyDatasetChanged()

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {}

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {}

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}


});
```

}

Comment: Thanks for it ! but it does not resolve my purpose if I remove order by. I would not be able to sort conversation based on time whenever child node change.